# Name of children cartoon with friendly colorful aliens that could create bubbles, tacker and tape

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I am looking for the name of a cartoon series in which friendly aliens save the world. Unfortunately I am not able to find good keywords for Google.

I remember (hopefully correctly):

- each alien has one primary colour
- each alien has a special ability: blowing bubbles (red one), tackering, taping, flying (yellow one)
- everything bad that happens on earth happens revered on the aliens home planet. For example in one episode the villain cause trees to fly into the sky like rockets on earth, and they vanish into the ground on the home planet

Comment: Could you explain what "tackering" is?  I assume "fyling" is flying, but is "taping" meaning recording? Creating a fastening material?  Was this an English-language series?  Do you know roughly what timeframe (e.g. decade) it was created?

Comment: I watched it in German in the late 1980s. Thanks to Systems' answer, I just learned that the names of the characters are derived from the English words related to their abilities. But 20 years ago, I did not know a single word of English, so it was just names for me. Sorry for the bad translations in my question.

Comment: No need to apologise :)  It just would have been easier to find 'stapling' than 'tackering' (and taping was taping, as odd as that sounds!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Diplodos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diplodos)! I loved that cartoon. I can still sing the theme song by heart :)

> The series Diplodo focuses on five dinosaur-like creatures, known as the diplodorians. These creatures are from Diplodorianrex, the sister planet of Earth, which lies in the fourth dimension. The story explains that whatever happens to one planet also affects the other planet. The Diplodos have successfully defended their home planet and put up a strong defensive shield. This results in the Diplidos' enemies, led by the evil Santos, targeting Earth in order to destroy the Diplodos' home planet. With this threat, the five chosen Diplodos travel to Earth in order to defend the planet, which will result in saving their own. Here, they meet and become allies with two children, Peter and Joan.

....

> **The Diplodos**
>
> - **Bubbles** – A pink hippo-like diplodorian. He is the leader of the Diplodos, he can produce bubbles from his mouth; capable of transporting human beings and possibly an evolved Tyrannosaurus. He is voiced by Arthur Grosser.
> - **Puncher** – A purple diplodorian who can punch holes through any material using his teeth and possibly an evolved Heterodontosaurus. He is voiced by Rick Jones.
> - **Scissors** – A yellow Pterosaur-like diplodorian who can slice objects using his mouth like a pair of scissors and is possibly an evolved Pteranodon.
> - **Stapler** – A blue walrus-like diplodorian who can produce staples from his mouth and is shown to be an evolved Triceratops.
> - **Stickum** – An orange Stegosaur-like diplodorian who can produce sellotape from his mouth, useful for repairing holes or tying up enemies and possibly an evolved Stegosaurus.